# filter in Apache-Spark filtering more rows in RDD than expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter

I have an RDD, which looks closely to this

> 1.0,2.0,0.0019,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,3.0,0.0,3.0E-4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,5.0,-0.0019,-2.0E-4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,8.4294
>   1.0,6.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,7.0,0.0,1.0E-4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,8.0,0.0,3.0E-4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,9040.8,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,9.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,10.0,-0.0033,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,47.03,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
>   1.0,11.0,0.0,-3.0E-4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,554.54,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,8140.58,0.0

I need to filter rows where the number of zeros equals a specific number, lets say 15. This definition of filter method is filtering more rows than expected.

```
def filterZeroRowsWReadings(row: Array[String]) = {
    var flag:Int = 0
    for(value <- row) {
      if(value.toDouble == 0.0)
        flag = flag + 1
    }
    flag match {
        case 15 => false
        case _ => true
    }
}
```

But I have manually counted the rows with number of zeros to 3,834 in a subset of my RDD, but the above filter method is removing 3,960 rows. Now, I don't understand where are these 126 rows going? Is there a way I could find out what is happening. On smaller RDD the result is as expected, but on large RDD it is somehow unexpected.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's a precision issue? You could try comparing each value as a string to "0.0" and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Spot on, I did that and it is working as expected. But this should not had happened. 0.00003 != 0.0

Comment: Depends on your machine. 0.00003 shouldn't be an issue, but 3E-60 might be. You might wish to print out the lines with discrepancies using collect() and compare these lines to your manual method. It's possible your manual method is the one which is broken. Kindly mark the answer below as "correct" for future reference.

Comment: No, the manual method is perfect, as verified by the new comparison with string. The lowest value in my RDD is around 3E-4, so not that small. I am wondering why is that the case. 3E-60 makes sense but 3E-4 does not. Can you please explain or provide a link, why it is machine dependent?

Comment: If the lowest value is 3E-4 then I would be suspicious. Rounding should not occur at that scale. What is you "manual method"?

Comment: By construction, the RDD produced must have those 15 0.0s consecutively, so I just counted the number of occurrences of 0.0,0.0 ... 0.0 (15 times) and it was my manual count of what I was trying to do programmatically. It was no coincidence that the count with manual method and with string comparison came out to be exactly the same. The problem probably is not with the manual counting method, but with the double comparison. I still fail to understand why this could be.

Comment: If you'd like to do more digging, you could write a script that loops through all the values and checks for cases of value != "0.0" && value.toDouble == 0.0. I'd guess there is some edge case that wasn't considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a precision issue? You could try comparing each value as a string to "0.0" and see if that changes anything.